# How to get Date and current time from the Date/Time column in SharePoint Custom list

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have column called "Date Submitted" as Date/time in one of the Custom list in sharepoint 2007.
it always set to today's date and 12AM time instead of that I want to display today's date with current time hh:mm:ss.

I tried creating calculated column TestDate and formula is : =TEXT(([Date Submitted]),"mm dd yyyy h:MM:SS")

result is 04 28 2010 0:00:00 I wanted to be 04/28/2010 10:50:34

Is it possible to achive this?

Thank you
kanta

Answer (score 9):

try to put =NOW() in the default value field in the column properties

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of Date Submitted, is the Date and Time Format currently Date Only? If so, try changing it to Date & Time.

Comment: In my tests this only set the time to the next full hour. E.g. if put in at 10:50 it would default to 11:00

Comment: Thank you Rich and Ryan,

Date Submitted is Date and Time but still get the same result.

Thank you
Kanta

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas to get you started :-

- Can you use the Created date instead - it will always be set to the exact time the record was created?
- When entering a new item on the Calendar list it defaults to the current time - could you make your list from a modified Calendar list rather than the Custom list?
- I've written a blog post about how you can use a JavaScript hack to set the default duration for a new calendar record - you could modify this to use with a Custom list and to set the field to the current time.

  [Setting a default duration for new calendar events](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/09/setting-default-duration-for-new-calender-events/)
- You could write your own custom field type

  [SharePoint 2007 Custom Date Time Field to default the time to the current time](http://www.mtelligent.com/journal/2007/9/29/sharepoint-2007-custom-date-time-field-to-default-the-time-t.html)

  [Codeplex - custom date time field](http://customdatetimefield.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I you for the link. I will go throug it.This is not a Calendar list . Could you explain 
" could you make your list from a modified Calendar list rather than the Custom list"

Thank you
Kanta

Comment: When you are creating your list you're starting with the empty "Custom List" template. If instead you start with a Calendar List then the start time will default to the next full hour - e.g. if its 10:50 when you enter the record it will default to 11:00

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I ended up creating a custom action which is called from a workflow.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Daniel. But How to go about it.

Thank you
Kanta

Answer (score 0):

=TEXT([DateFiled Here],"mm/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss ")

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do what you want:

```
=TEXT(Today,"mm/dd/YYYY")&" "&TEXT(Now(),"h:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I found that adding the additional function "Now" would return the present time, rather than returning time from the "Today" function which would only return, "00:00:00"