# How to get the Current Date & Time Automatically to a Date Time Field

Tags: sharepoint, datetime

I have created a date time field I made today's date as the default value, Then I added it to a page layout and created a page, But the current Date Time is not picking up from the system.

I dont want to give the user to select a Date Time instead it should populated automatically

Is there anyway to achieve this without writing code in code behind files?

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to this question I think

- [SO - How to get Date and current time from the Date/Time column in SharePoint Custom list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731079/how-to-get-date-and-current-time-from-the-date-time-column-in-sharepoint-custom-l/2732809#2732809)

My answer there gives a few options such as using the built in Created field, using a calendar template, a JavaScript hack and a custom field type.

Answer (score 0):

Guys, fake [Today] trick worked for us - but prob is we only got the date value not datetime.

Janis, is it possible to get date and time both from the fake [today] column trick? pls refer few articles on the same

Comment: The fake today trick does not work reliably and even if it did its not going to give you date & time.

* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878744/any-solution-to-the-today-calculated-column-problem-is-sharepoint
* http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/
* http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/08/14/calculated-columns-the-useless-today-trick/

Answer (score -1):

Does **[Today]** work?

If you have language pack applied to SharePoint, then you must use localized "Today" string.

Comment: Hi Janis, when we use Today - it gives following error "Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me."

It seems today cannot be used as a calculated column function.

What we think is having a DATETIME field which will populate the current datetime only which needs to be coming from the system wihtout any coding. Is this possible? After this we can created a calculated text column to show the date time in a format we desire. But we stuck at the first problem.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use TODAY in calculated columns - and the oft repeated fake column trick doesn't work.
http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/

Comment: Without even the fake column trick? How can it doesn't work? It must work: http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/

Comment: If you read the comments in this or any other article mentioning the trick you will see "It works great, Thanks!" then a few days later "Oh - its not working any more". Try it for yourself (but make sure you check again tomorrow). 

More details on why it doesn't work 
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878744/any-solution-to-the-today-calculated-column-problem-is-sharepoint
* http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/
* http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/08/14/calculated-columns-the-useless-today-trick/